# Placing barButtons on Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am adding an image to my UINavigationBar. Its 100 pixels long (yeah a very long navigation bar). I need to add some barbuttons to the first row (within in the first 44 pixels), and to add another few barbuttons to the next row (within the next 44 pixels).

How can i do this programatically ?

[image]

Those 4 boxes are barButtons, and how can i place them at those positions ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can control the placement of barButtons like this without using private APIs. You might consider replacing the UINavigationBar with your own custom UIView, or perhaps adding a separate view below the UINavigationBar and make them visually look integrated.

Comment: Although this is definitely a good solution. I would discourage this interface, @sharon, try to re-design the interface using Apple's UI. It will be easier in the long run.